# suppress logging in spring batch 3

Tags: spring, logging

I am writing a spring-batch application, based on an example I found.   When I run it in Eclipse, it produces some annoying INFO logs from deep inside the framework.   I'd like to suppress that, so only my System.out statements show - for clarity.

I figured the logging is from the inherited `commons-logging1.1.1.jar`, that's in my classpath, because when I take out that reference I get errors about Logger.

Question1:  Which framework is used for logging in my sample application and how can I change the default INFO to WARN?

Question2:  will adopting Log4j just override this default behavior?

Comment: commons logging is just a facade to underlying logging framework.  Find out what you are using now, and configure that accordingly (e.g. turning off logging for certain logger).  The question has nothing to do with Spring Batch

Comment: that's the thing... I have no idea what framework is used to trace out the logs that I see....:

Comment: 'Sep 13, 2017 5:37:48 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1d56ce6a: startup date [Wed Sep 13 17:37:48 MDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Sep 13, 2017 5:37:48 PM '

Comment: I can attach the pom.xml file that this project has.... there is no clear refernece to a logging framework that i can see....

Comment: As far as I know, Spring Batch is not using commons-logging as logging facade.  Instead it is using SLF4J.  Check if slf4j JAR is in your classpath / dependencies.  If so, further check which implemetation your project is using.  You should either find logback or slf4j-XXXX.jar  (XXXX may be log4j etc).  Then you know what is the logging impl you are using

Comment: If you are using maven, do a `mvn dependency:tree` and it should give you a summary on what's the effective dependencies of your project. You need to remember Maven dependencies are transitive.

Comment: It won't let me paste the list into this comment window.... here is the link to the image produced by mvn dependency:tree command:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/nNoW1HZCQnq5Mlxr2

Comment: You should update your question

Comment: I don't understand what you mean:  the pic I posted clearly shows there are no logging frameworks in the dependency list or in my classpath in Eclipse, yet spring is logging at INFO level... how?

Comment: Can't you update the question with information needed? Why post a pic when you can post text ? Btw, I remembered wrong. Spring use common logging as logging facade. If no logging framework available , commons logging fallback to simple log, which you can learn how to configure at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/SimpleLog.html

Comment: Why post a pic?!   Because it wouldn't let me post all that text in this little comment space.  Now we finally arrive at the core of the question:   which framework is used and how to override the INFO default.  Thx for the info.   I'm going to create 'simplelog.properties' file in my /resources and override the default logging level in there.   Thank you much.

Comment: EDIT the question, not posting in comment!

Comment: I misunderstood you... sorry.   Here is my final answer:
I've create two property files under /resources:
commons-logging.properties, with this:
`org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog`, and simplelog.properties, with this: `org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.defaultlog=warn`
It worked.   Thanks -

Answer (score 0):

I've create two property files under /resources: commons-logging.properties, with this: org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.im‌​pl.SimpleLog, and simplelog.properties, with this: org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.defaultlog=warn It worked. Thanks - –